# Add timestamp on sitelink

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i want to add timestamp to my site

example.com/?**timestamp**

so if if link is

```
example.com/#ch-30
```

will be like this

```
example.com/?210220161833#ch-30
```

i tried with this code and it add index.php (example.com/index.php#ch-30)
so can i replace index.php with ?timestamp

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#only for the root directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You can add a timestamp using `%{TIME_SEC}` however The server wont see the anything after the # so it won't send that too. It's better if you use Javascript to manipulate the URL. It can do this.

Comment: how should be the code for .htaccess